# Migrate Cometd 2 to Cometd3 in Glassfish- Handshake fail

Tags: servlets, glassfish, cometd

I migrated my cometd from 2 to 3 and come across some problem:
Handshake never succeed, and there's no error messages.
I tried all I can do but still in vain.
Here's my Code:

**ConfigurationServlet:**

```
 @Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    logger.info("start prepare echoService...");
    // Grab the Bayeux object
    BayeuxServer bayeuxServer = (BayeuxServer) getServletContext().getAttribute(BayeuxServer.ATTRIBUTE);
    bayeuxServer.createChannelIfAbsent(NODE_CHANNEL, new ServerChannel.Initializer() { //1030829 change createIfAbsend to createChannelIfAbsent
        @Override
        public void configureChannel(ConfigurableServerChannel channel) {
            channel.setPersistent(true);
        }
    });

    EchoService echoService = new EchoService(bayeuxServer);
    logger.info("...prepare echoService done");

}
```

**EchoService:**

```
 public EchoService(BayeuxServer bayeuxServer) {
    super(bayeuxServer, "echo");
    //for what?
    logger.info("=============enter echoService constructor=============");
    addService("/echo", "processEcho");
    addService(CometdProperties.COMETD_CHANNEL_WEB, "processReq");
    logger.info("=============leaving echoService constructor=============");
    isEchoServiceStarted = true;
}

public void processEcho(ServerSession remote, ServerMessage message) {
    remote.deliver(getServerSession(), "/echo", message.getData());
}

public void processReq(ServerSession remote, ServerMessage message) {
//do something...
}
```

**InitConnect in my client:**

```
public boolean initConnect(String channel, ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener ml) {
    HClogger.info("=============initConnect=============Listener:" + ml);
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    try {
        httpClient.start();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        HClogger.error(ex.toString());
         if(connCnt<10){//Retry 9 times.
        connCnt++;
        return initConnect(channel,ml);
        }
        return false;
    }
    HClogger.info("*********************************try connect to server...");
    Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
    ClientTransport longPool = new LongPollingTransport(options, httpClient);
    bayeuxClient = new BayeuxClient(CometdProperties.COMETD_DEFAULTURL, longPool);
    bayeuxClient.handshake();
    boolean handshaken = bayeuxClient.waitFor(10000, BayeuxClient.State.CONNECTED);
    if (handshaken) {
        HClogger.info("connected to server ok...");
        bayeuxClient.getChannel(channel).subscribe(ml);
        HClogger.info("subscribed to " + channel + " channel.");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000); 
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            HClogger.error("Error when sleep after subscribe.", ex);
        }
        HClogger.info("=============HandleClient subscribe done.=============");
        return true;
    } else {
        HClogger.info("=============HandleClient handshake fail.=============");
        if(connCnt<10){//Retry 9 times.
        connCnt++;
        return initConnect(channel,ml);
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.cometd.server.CometDServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>timeout</param-name>
        <param-value>300000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>   

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ConfigurationServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.astri.ims.ccs.webcommand.ConfigurationServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ConfigurationServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ConfigurationServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And here's what I add in my lib:

- bayeux-api-3.0.1.jar
- cometd-java-client-3.0.1.jar
- cometd-java-common-3.0.1.jar
- cometd-java-server-2.0.1.jar
- jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.12.jar
- javax.servlet-3.1.jar
- jetty-client-9.2.2v20140723.jar
- jetty-http-9.2.2v20140723.jar
- jetty-io-9.2.2v20140723.jar
- jetty-jmx-9.2.2v20140723.jar
- jetty-server-9.2.2v20140723.jar
- jetty-servlet-9.2.2v20140723.jar
- jetty-util-9.2.2v20140723.jar
- jetty-util-ajax-9.2.2v20140723.jar

Is there anything wrong in my code or configuration?

### Update

I added a listener to the meta_channel, and I got this while handshaking:

```
{"id":"3","failure":{"message":{"id":"3","supportedConnectionTypes":["long-polling"],"channel":"/meta/handshake","version":"1.0"},"exception":"java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Total timeout elapsed","connectionType":"long-polling"},"subscription":null,"successful":false,"channel":"/meta/handshake"}
```

Comment: If you enable debug logging on the server, what does it say (see http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_troubleshooting)? Are you sure the CometD URL you point to is correct?

Comment: I enabled debug and it says nothing.  The CometD URL worked before I migrate and I didn't change it, so I think the URL is no problem.

Comment: The failure you get on the handshake indicates that you get a timeout on the client while trying to handshake. This may be caused by network problems or by a too long processing on server side. You may want to post your server debug logs on the CometD mailing list for further analysis.

Comment: @sbordet Thank you, but I've build another small project to just test my code and config about CometD3. There are no codes other than CometD in this new project, but the problem still remains. In this new small project, there are only three java file: ConfigurationServlet, EchoService, and a client used to test handshake : MyClient.

Comment: To make you easier understand what I've done, please download my code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4vfusiekbcpbrp/Cometd3.zip?dl=0

Comment: And thank you for suggest me to post on the CometD mailing list. I've done that and waiting for article approvement.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine using CometD 3 with Jetty 9.2.2. What application server are you using ?

Comment: I'm using glassfish 4.0, which supports Servlet3.1 I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a bug in glassfish4.
Thanks for @sbordet who investigate and find out what's going on.
For detail information, please [visit here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cometd-users/vXFPsMdLVaw).

For those who want to use CometD3, Jetty is suggested container.
For those who have no choice but to use glassfish, Cometd2.X works.
I've tried with cometd2.9.1, 3.0.0 and 3.0.1 in glassfish4, the result is 
2.9.1 works in glassfish4 while 3.0.0 and 3.0.1 not.